# Visual Studio 2013 - Debug options missing under configuration options

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I need to pass command line arguments to my c# project, I know I need to go solution properties, configuration options and under that I should be able to see debug options and within that there should be a field to pass in command line arguments - The problem I have is that I can't see the debug options, do I need to install something? Anyone's experienced this before?

thanks

EDIT: screenshot added

[image]

Comment: Take a screenshot of your configuration options page and add it to the question. Use SnippingTool.exe, it is built in to windows to take easy screenshots.

Comment: 97% answer: Having project type to be on of "executable" types (and not class library) would help...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov not really, [this is from a class library project](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt6BZ.png)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain that's what 3% where for :) also we may never know what type of project OP actually started with...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I have added a screenshot

Comment: And I've already posted the answer (I had to re-read the question to see the line where you mention solution properties instead of project properties)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the **Project** properties, not the Solution configuration, to access the Debug settings and the command line arguments box. This is available to .exe and .dll projects.

Right-click the project name in Solution Explorer and select Properties at the bottom of the list.

Answer (score 2):

> I know I need to go solution properties

That is your problem, you need to go to the properties page of the project, not the solution.

When you go to the Debug tab of the project properites you should see something similar to this

[image]